# Why do I get "action navigate with payload undefined was not handled by any navigator"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to do a small project myself to get to know React-Native.

I have 2 screens, and i want to navigate from my SplashScreen to HomeScreen by pressing on the button. But it gives me an error.
What should I add to get rid of the error?

Here are the codes
App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; // react-navigation, must be on top
import React from 'react';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import SplashScreen from "./src/screens/SplashScreen.js";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen.js";


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {

  
  return (
    // name is whatever you write
    // initialRouteName is which screen you want as your initial
    // when I add title, it will write it as title, not whats written in "name"
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Intro" screenOptions={{title:"helllloo"}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Intro" component={SplashScreen} options={{title:"our intro"}} /> 
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    
  );
};



export default App;
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

SplashScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen";


const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  // without flex:1, it will center on that row, not on whole page
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
      <Button 
        title="Go to HomeScreen"
        onPress = {() => navigation.navigate(HomeScreen)}
      />
    </View>
  )
}


export default SplashScreen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you define route here `<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />`

the route name is `"Home"`
and route component `HomeScreen`

to navigate call `navigation.navigate(route name not route component)`

so replace this `navigation.navigate(HomeScreen)` with `navigation.navigate("Home")`

Comment: Btw where would you recommend me to learn react-native? the official documentation is best place to start?

Comment: the official documentation just offers the basics like component, props, state, etc.., so it is good for basics but you can't create app only with it. you Strongly need to thirdy party libraries such as navigation, ui libraries, native apis like camera, location, notification, datepicker, ...etc, and every libray has small doc, you need first to read it carfully and search google for articles about every library for best use

Comment: for navigation the doc of reactnavigation is good to understand and have alot of examples  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: thank you for answering. I understand, just one more question. For example, lets say now I need to navigate from a screen to another. So i should just read the related part of react navigation document, or i should finish react navigation document?

Comment: you are welcome, ok. for navigation library read only part you need, because it has alot packages inside it, if you use stack navigation in you app there is no need to read about bottom tabs navigation in this time, but when reading stack navigation docs read whole it carefully and know most solutions that offered. that well help you for good learning.

Comment: using react native cli is good rather expo.